# Angular error while building because external library - Unexpected value "BannerModule..."

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, ng-packagr, angular-library

I created a library in order to share some components between two different projects, using ng-packagr module.

The structure of the lib is 
[image]

**In my library**

The src/package.json :

```
{
  "name": "my-ng-library",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "ngPackage": {
    "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
    "lib": {
      "entryFile": "index.ts"
    },
    "dest": "../dist"
  },
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {},
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19",
    "compass-mixins": "^0.12.10"
  }
}
```

src/components/banner/banner.module.ts:

```
import { BannerComponent } from './banner.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [BannerComponent],
  exports: [BannerComponent],
  providers: []
})
export class BannerModule { }
```

src/index.ts:

```
export { BannerModule } from './components/banner/banner.module';
export { BannerComponent } from './components/banner/banner.component';
```

**In the client app**

app.module.ts:

```
import { BannerModule } from 'my-ng-library/dist';
@NgModule({
  declarations:[
    BannerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BannerModule  
  ]
})
```

Everything is working fine, serving the app in local, but when I try to build for prod I get the following error:

> ERROR in : Unexpected value 'BannerModule in /Users/username/Dev/Work/app-mobile-network-site/node_modules/my-ng-library/dist/components/banner/banner.module.d.ts' imported by the module 'AppModule in /Users/username/Dev/Work/Essence/app-mobile-network-site/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Comment: Have you tried to run npm install? Maybe you are missing files in node_modules folder.

Comment: What is the version of `"@angular/core"` in your application?

Comment: @NishantGhodke 5.2 in both (lib and app)

Comment: @FunkRehkitz yes of course, I can easily run app in local, but I cannot build it for production

Comment: I'm having a near identical problem with Angular 6.0.8: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51147293/unexpected-value-xxx-imported-by-the-module-xxx-please-add-a-ngmodule-annotatio