# Unexpected value xxx imported by the module xxx Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, typescript, build, production-environment, angular6

I'm attempting to convert an existing Angular app from 5.2.5 to 6.0.8. After some time struggling with an error, I've created a relatively straightforward repro which can be found here:

https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Angular6Issue

The error on my machine comes out as:

```
ERROR in : Unexpected value 'TestModule in C:/Source/angular6issue/test/app/node_modules/test-package-a6/dist/index.d.ts' imported by the module 'AppModule in C:/Source/angular6issue/test/app/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

**Edit:** Note that it's just building for production that I'm having an issue with - it builds and runs fine in dev mode

Comment: Packaging an angular library is more than just compiling TypeScript. Use the support for libraries that the CLI offers: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library

Comment: @JBNizet As per the edit, it builds/runs fine without --prod. If it's related to packaging, what have I missed, exactly?

Comment: Looks like I just found a similar problem with 5.2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50988187/angular-error-while-building-because-external-library-unexpected-value-banner

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing a similar problem.

Comment: @Kolby The solution was to start a new project using the "new" way of creating Angular libraries. The method we ended up using was based around this article: https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5. There are a number of other articles covering the process; just Google for: create library angular 6

Comment: Thanks Dave. This ended up bring my problem: https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/355

Apparently this error message isn't a good one and can occur from a number of different problems.